# How do you provide an extra parameter to a function call if the argument is implicitly provided?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
export const SelectedChoice: (choiceProps) => { ... }

<ChoicePicker {...props}

     onRenderItem={SelectedChoice}

/>
```

I have this, the argument choiceProps is implicitly provided, but now I want to add a function to the second argument so I can call it inside of SelectedChoice, how do I do this? The issue is that I don't know what is being passed to SelectedChoice so I can't call it explicitly without breaking the function. If I knew what was being passed as choiceProps, I wouldn't have this issue. I feel like it's being called as a callback function and the argument is explicitly provided inside onRenderItem, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Do you know how many arguments pass through the ```SelectedChoice``` function?

Comment: It's only 1 argument and it's called choiceProps. I want to also pass a function as a callback.

Comment: Have you try something like this? ```onRenderItem={choiceProps => SelectedChoice(choiceProps, your_second_argv)}```

Comment: That's a really good idea, actually, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to check the `arguments` object that implicitly exists in the function body of `SelectedChoice` as in:

```
export const SelectedChoice: (choiceProps) => {
   if(arguments.length === 1) {
      // do something if no function was passed
   }
   else if(arguments.length === 2 && typeof arguments[1] === "function") {
      // call the passed function
      arguments[1]();
   }
}
```